# Category / Custom Post Type permalink issue

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

So I'm currently working on a client site and trying to switch some old posts over to use new custom post types.  Prior to this point, her website was set up in such a way that she could add both books with chapters as well as uncategorized advice columns to her site.  In order to add either of these items, she would add a new post, and stick them in a specific category.  If she wanted the post to show up as a chapter in her book, she filed it under the correct subcategory of the "books" category.  If she wanted the post to show up in her advice columns, she would add it to the "advice" category.

Permalinks for this site were set up in such a way that when reading an individual chapter of a book, it would look like so "/books/*the-book/the-chapter*"

Now, I'm trying to recombobulate her set up a bit.  Instead of simply adding a new post and categorizing it to achieve this effect, I split out the two different areas into their own custom post types (called *chapter* and *column*).  When setting up the new custom post type, I'm trying to set up the rewrite argument to use the same permalink that was used previously, however it appears that even after deleting the category, the permalink is still reserved by the category.  What I mean is I receive 404's when trying to access "/books/the-book/the-chapter", but if I change the rewrite to use "chapter", or another base, it works.

Mainly I'm wondering if there's a way to fix this, and what could be causing this.  It has to do with the fact that the category still existed when the CPT was initially added, but I can't quite nail it down.

Here's the website where you can see it in action: http://dev1.abileneloving.com

Here's my code for the CPT/Custom Tax/Custom Permalink Structure:

```
function chapter_post_type_init() {
        $labels = array(
                'name' => 'Chapters',
                'singular_name' => 'Chapter',
                'add_new' => 'Add New',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Chapter',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Chapter',
                'new_item' => 'New Chapter',
                'all_items' => 'All Chapters',
                'view_item' => 'View Chapter',
                'search_items' => 'Search Chapters',
                'not_found' =>  'No chapters found',
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'No chapters found in Trash',
                'parent_item_colon' => '',
                'menu_name' => 'Books'
        );

        $args = array(
                'labels' => $labels,
                'public' => true,
                'publicly_queryable' => true,
                'show_ui' => true,
                'show_in_menu' => true,
                'query_var' => true,
                'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'books/%book_type%'),
                'capability_type' => 'post',
                'has_archive' => true,
                'hierarchical' => false,
                'menu_position' => 100,
                'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'excerpt')
        );
        register_post_type( 'chapter', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'chapter_post_type_init' );

function book_tax_init() {
        $labels = array(
                'name'              => _x( 'Books', 'taxonomy general name' ),
                'singular_name'     => _x( 'Book', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
                'search_items'      => __( 'Search Books' ),
                'all_items'         => __( 'All Books' ),
                'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Book' ),
                'update_item'       => __( 'Update Book' ),
                'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Book' ),
                'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Book Name' ),
                'menu_name'         => __( 'Books' ),
        );

        $args = array(
                'hierarchical'      => true,
                'labels'            => $labels,
                'show_ui'           => true,
                'show_admin_column' => true,
                'query_var'         => true,
                'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'books/%book_type%')
        );
        register_taxonomy(
                'book',
                'chapter',
                $args
        );
}

add_action( 'init', 'book_tax_init' );

add_filter('post_type_link', 'book_permalink_structure', 10, 4);
function book_permalink_structure($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample)
{
    if ( false !== strpos( $post_link, '%book_type%' ) ) {
        $book_type_term = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'book' );
        $post_link = str_replace( '%book_type%', array_pop( $book_type_term )->slug, $post_link );
    }
    return $post_link;
}
```

**Update - New Code**

```
function chapter_post_type_init() {
        $labels = array(
                'name' => 'Chapters',
                'singular_name' => 'Chapter',
                'add_new' => 'Add New',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Chapter',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Chapter',
                'new_item' => 'New Chapter',
                'all_items' => 'All Chapters',
                'view_item' => 'View Chapter',
                'search_items' => 'Search Chapters',
                'not_found' =>  'No chapters found',
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'No chapters found in Trash',
                'parent_item_colon' => '',
                'menu_name' => 'Books'
        );

        $args = array(
                'labels' => $labels,
                'public' => true,
                'publicly_queryable' => true,
                'show_ui' => true,
                'show_in_menu' => true,
                'query_var' => true,
                'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'books/%book%'),
                'capability_type' => 'post',
                'has_archive' => true,
                'hierarchical' => false,
                'menu_position' => 100,
                'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'excerpt')
        );
        register_post_type( 'chapter', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'chapter_post_type_init' );

function book_tax_init() {
        $labels = array(
                'name'              => _x( 'Books', 'taxonomy general name' ),
                'singular_name'     => _x( 'Book', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
                'search_items'      => __( 'Search Books' ),
                'all_items'         => __( 'All Books' ),
                'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Book' ),
                'update_item'       => __( 'Update Book' ),
                'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Book' ),
                'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Book Name' ),
                'menu_name'         => __( 'Books' ),
        );

        $args = array(
                'hierarchical'      => true,
                'labels'            => $labels,
                'show_ui'           => true,
                'show_admin_column' => true,
                'query_var'         => true,
                'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'books')
        );
        register_taxonomy(
                'book',
                'chapter',
                $args
        );
}

add_action( 'init', 'book_tax_init' );

add_filter('post_type_link', 'book_permalink_structure', 10, 4);
function book_permalink_structure($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample)
{
    if ( false !== strpos( $post_link, '%book%' ) ) {
        $book_type_term = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'book' );
        $post_link = str_replace( '%book%', array_pop( $book_type_term )->slug, $post_link );
    }
    return $post_link;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues-

- there is no `%book_type%` rewrite tag, your rewrite tags are `%book%` and `%chapter%`. Change all instances of `%book_type%` to `%book%`.
- Your taxonomy slug should just be `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'books')`, the rewrite tag shouldn't be in there.
- Last (minor) issue- In your `post_type_link` filter, you should wrap the fetching of the book term in an `if` check so you only try to replace the tag if a term is selected. otherwise, with debugging enabled you'll see a `trying to get property of non-object` notice from trying to get the slug of a non-existent term.

  ```
  if( $book_type_term = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'book' ) )
      $post_link = str_replace( '%book%', array_pop( $book_type_term )->slug, $post_link );
  ```

tested and working in twentythirteen theme- visit your permalinks settings page after making changes, to flush rewrite rules, and all should work as expected.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but you say there isn't a `%book_type%` rewrite tag, however if I'm correct, isn't the rewrite tag "defined" in my post_type_link filter through the `str_replace` function?  Why would changing from `%book_type%` to `%book%` help?  I use the same setup with "type" appended to it for another CPT on the same blog and it works as expected.  Not sure why that isn't the case for this one.

Comment: your rewrite tags are defined when you register your post type and taxonomy, they're used by WordPress to convert a request into the necessary query vars to query the database. you can see them exposed on the front end if you set permalinks to default, disabling pretty permalinks, then you'll have URLs like `/?book=some-book` or `/?chapter=a-chapter`

Comment: So you're saying that rewrite tags are by default automatically created to match the post type query var key?

Comment: yes, that's correct.

Comment: I'll check this tomorrow and see if it solves my issue.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: After trying your recommendations, I'm still receiving 404s on my "books" page, but now taxonomies within books seem to be working (like "books/loving-house-family-intentions").  I've updated my permalinks also.  Any idea?

Comment: update your question with the code you're currently using.

Comment: Updated to include new code

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by books page. Your code works for showing all the chapters in a book, and showing an individual chapter within a book. If you mean literally the URL `/books/` showing all books, that's not something that should work- there is no concept of a taxonomy-wide archive, only a taxonomy term archive.

Comment: How would I create a taxonomy wide template then?  I page which shows all the books within the books taxonomy?  My goal is to have a books taxonomy where all books can be uploaded, and then a cpt for cahpters.  The chapters can then be sorted into books.  I want the user to be able to go to "/books" and see a list of all books with their description.  I was under the impression that this would be handled by the archive template.

Comment: taxonomies don't work that way, it's the same with built in tags or categories- there's no page that shows all categories or all tags, the individual terms are the archives. you'd have to create a books page and output all of your taxonomy terms on that page via get_terms. personally, I would make both a cpt and relate chapters to books by storing the parent book ID in the chapter's post_parent field, or in post meta data.

Comment: Thank you stranger.  I think I understand now.  I'll figure out how to work around this issue on Monday.  Thanks for all the help.